# insert a lot of data to database php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert, bigdata

I want insert about 19000 data to mysql database with php , but with load page or cron job just added about 2000 , how can i insert all data

```
foreach($inventories as $item){
     $this->model->AddInventory($item);
}
```

Comment: You have to give more information, and 19000 rows it 's not a big data query

Comment: @iLikeMySql If you have to get the data from a CSV file and modify it/check for duplicates in a database, 19k is quite a lot of data for php to handle. It seems like the problem you are having is the script timing out because it takes too long.

Comment: @iLikeMySql my file is a serialize file but perhaps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron job and load page both are basically same thing, cron job just hit the url for you after defined interval of time.
in your case there may be the reason of php execution time out (default execution time is 30 seconds), now you have 2 options

1. increase php max_execution_time in php.ini file
2. execute your script via command line

I would recommend to use command line, altering max_execution_time is not the right approach